# Mechanize gem does not submit my form

Tags: web-crawler, mechanize

I am using [Mechanize gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) to do a crawler to my Rails App. I want to login, but I am stopped here.

```
  def start_login
    begin
      login_page = mechanize.get("http://myservice:31031/login")
      login_form = login_page.form_with(:action => '/login') do |f|
        f.field_with(:name => "user[username]").value = "user"
        f.field_with(:name => "user[password]" ).value = "password"
      end.submit
    rescue Exception => exception
      puts exception.message
    end
  end
```

But the submit does not send me to the new page, it just redirect to the same page. I did some test with others sites and I can log in and inspect, but the only different between these test are the fields name. I don't know if it is important but the others fields have simple name (user_name, user_password), but here I am using a hash.... I am really lost!!!

When I inspect the login_form after the submit action:

```
puts login_form.inspect
```

It is the output:

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url #<URI::HTTP:0x00000002ba0728 URL:http://myservice:31031/login>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "\nBeesor\n"}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name nil}
   {method "POST"}
   {action "/login"}
   {fields
    [hidden:0x15fae14 type: hidden name: utf8 value: ✓]
    [hidden:0x15fa7ac type: hidden name: authenticity_token value: d+BaksCcM3MHVi0hdENu9EIIia17KsROLfbTqqyrWPs=]
    [text:0x15fa0f4 type: text name: user[username] value: ]
    [field:0x15f9b2c type: password name: user[password] value: ]}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons [submit:0x15f9960 type: submit name: commit value: ]}>}>
```